# How to send a token with an AJAX request from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, jwt, express-jwt

I use express-jwt and create my token via jQuery and save it in my localStorage with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  error : function(err) {
    console.log('Error!', err)
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Success!')
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.id_token);
  }
});
```

I have a protected route in my backend like:

```
app.get('/upload',jwt({secret: config.secret}), function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/upload.html'));
});
```

**How can I send the token from localStorage with the request header?**

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can set the headers in a [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  type: 'GET',
  // Fetch the stored token from localStorage and set in the header
  headers: {"Authorization": localStorage.getItem('token')}
});
```

Comment: why you send token into headers? why not into data ??

Comment: @ahmedbhs I believe his trying to protect token somehow.

Comment: for a JWT header, this worked for me `headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token }`

Comment: You should be very careful when exposing your JWT token, in Javascript like a variable. Definitely don't expose it in frontend https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/20/what-happens-if-your-jwt-is-stolen

Answer (score 10):

If you are using JWT authentication then this is how you add it to the headers in .ajax() method:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
}
```

,

Answer (score 5):

I use the approach below to cover JWT authentication with the result status types

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
  type: "POST",
  headers: { Authorization: $`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` },
  data: formData,
  error: function(err) {
    switch (err.status) {
      case "400":
        // bad request
        break;
      case "401":
        // unauthorized
        break;
      case "403":
        // forbidden
        break;
      default:
        //Something bad happened
        break;
    }
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Success!");
  }
});
```

Comment: but the question was how to send the saved token with the request. not how to save the token after the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this if you're using JWT,

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'get', // or any other method you want
        dataType: 'json', 
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        },
        url: `your-endpoint`,
        success: (data, status, xhr) => {
            if (data.status) {
               //Do something
            } else {
                console.warn("AJax failed");
            }
        },
        error: (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) => {
            console.log(xhr.responseJSON.message);
        }
    });
```