# how to create Ajax header get method authentication bearer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to call data JSON from URL, and the source need authentication bearer
I create in codeigniter framework this is my reference [link](https://github.com/dodistyo/ci-rest-jwt)

and here is my code,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Token': Bearer +'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTg1MjA0LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxODg4MDR9.dG13Tv62YHgdH9SD1HKPCc_JSAVgqrJb70UlR-bqy4E'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function (data, status, xhr) { 
        console.log(status); 
        console.log(xhr); 
    }
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Bearer` should be a the string "Bearer" - and usually you'd use `Authorization` as the header, but if the API requires `Token` then that's fine - though, reading the documentation you linked to, but obviously haven't read, the header should be `Authorization` not `Token` ... and as stated the `Bearer` is part of the header value, i.e. it's a literal string

Comment: i.e. your code would look like `Authentication: 'Bearer "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTg1MjA0LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxODg4MDR9.dG13Tv62YHgdH9SD1HKPCc_JSAVgqrJb70UlR-bqy4E"'`

Comment: headers: { 'Token' : Bearer "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTg5MjA5LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxOTI4MDl9.zSedo6KmsdKYnbIDxNBag79QQjPh_V4spFnqt4XS4ZQ"}, like this?

Comment: i'am using Token not Authentication. thats right in documentation use authentication but i test with postman just works when i'm using Token @JaromandaX

Comment: well, then the only problem is that you are trying to use a variable named `Bearer` instead of the string `Bearer` - and perhaps the token part needs to be in `"` - but since your actual requirements only partially resemble the code you're basing it on, then you'll need to tweak those minutiae

Comment: headers: { 'Token' : 'Bearer'+'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTg5MjA5LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxOTI4MDl9.zSedo6KmsdKYnbIDxNBag79QQjPh_V4spFnqt4XS4ZQ'}, like this? @JaromandaX

Comment: It should be like `"Token": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTg1MjA0LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxODg4MDR9.dG13Tv62YHgdH9SD1HKPCc_JSAVgqrJb70UlR-bqy4E"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a token with an AJAX request from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861012/how-to-send-a-token-with-an-ajax-request-from-jquery)

Comment: @PrateikDarji nope bro

Comment: is there any error in console after ajax call?

Comment: does the token need to be sent in quotes after the word "Bearer" ...only you know the server you're sending to, it's nothing like the example you linked to, so ...

Comment: @JaromandaX, so far I think now the problem is not in ajax but on configuration access control header API, because with the same ajax code i can get data from another url, do you have an idea?

Comment: My gut says the server side is expecting something other than what you are sending